# How to do 2 types of asynchronous tasks in parallel without disruption?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

The program I am writing needs to perform 2 types of tasks.

1. Connect to list of clients.
2. Do a series of tasks through connected clients.

Assuming that the program is doing things like this:

```
import asyncio

async def task(worker_id):
    print(f'worker {worker_id} start working ...')
    
    # The client actually comes from the Pyrogram library.
    client = Client(worker_id)

    await client.connect()

    for job in jobs:
        ... # await jobs
        print(f'job {job.id} finished!')
        

async def main():
    tasks = [task(_) for _ in range(10)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This program should execute the "task" function ten times and continue the process after each of them is connected, but what this program does is that it waits on connect until all 10 tasks are connected. It is currently connected and blocks the event loop.

How to separate the part that the program tries to connect from the part that is for doing things, so that the connection does not affect other things!

For example, whenever any of the clients are connected, will that client be taken in another part and do its work? (for example, asyncio.Queue should be used for sending and receiving between the sections)

```
import asyncio

queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def task():
    for client_id in clients:
        print(f'worker {client_id} start working ...')
        client = Client(client_id)
        await client.connect()
        await queue.put(client)

async def task2(client):
    client = await queue.get()
    for job in jobs:
        await client.do_job(job)
        print(f'job {job.id} finished!')
        

async def main():
    tasks = [task(), task2()]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use threads?

Comment: @CtrlZ I did this with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but still the connection requests interfered with `Task2` and caused slowness.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see your threading code

Comment: @CtrlZ sure, https://dpaste.org/LPG5z